# Are there two different unbounded sequences such that if you subtract them they converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having a hard time coming up with two unbounded sequences where their difference yields $0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Any ideas?

Comment: $s_n=n$, $t_n=n$, $s_n-t_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses

Comment: Forgot to say two different sequences.

Comment: Then how about $s_n = n+\frac{1}{n}$, $t_n = n$?

Comment: @JesseMartinez: As so many answers have come and so much time has passed it is time for you to read them learn from them and decide to accept one of them. It is a good practice to do that. (unless you fel the answers were unhelpful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any monotonic sequence diverging to $+\infty$, as the first sequence. Define the second sequence by adding $\frac1n$ to the $n$th term of the first.
What can you say bout the difference between these two sequences?

Answer (score 3):

Take $(\sqrt{n+1})$ and $(\sqrt n)$.

Answer (score 2):

$n$ and $n+\dfrac 1 n$. $\qquad\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_n = f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is a monotone function and let $b_n = f(n) + \frac{1}{n^m}$ for any $m > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest example: 
$$
a_n = n,
\qquad
b_n = \begin{cases}
n, & n > 1\\
0, & n = 1
\end{cases}
$$
for $n = 1,2, \dots$ These are (obviously) different, and their difference is (obviously) convergent to $0$:
$$
a_n - b_n = \begin{cases}
0, & n > 1\\
1, & n = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Arguably, these are not essentially different, but I think the whole point of this exercise is to realise that two sequences may be different, yet have very similar asymptotic behaviour.